# Pact Groovy Mock with Array in Body

Tags: groovy, pact, pact-jvm

I would like to model my much such that its body consists of an array of *n* elements. The below code only creates one element in the array, when it should produce three.

```
withBody(eachLike(3, {
   id identifier
   state("COMPLETED")
   type regexp("(A|B)", "A")
 }))
```

Oddly enough, if I name the name collection, it actually generates three objects:

```
withBody {
  namedObject eachLike(3, {
  id identifier
  })
}
```

Where do I go wrong? Is this a bug?

Comment: hm, seems like it could be a bug.  I don't know enough of pact jvm to comment fully however.  Your best bet is to create an issue on the repo: https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues

Comment: https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues/555