# How to generate a Pact file with a response body matching a array of Strings with groovy

Tags: arrays, groovy, pact, pact-jvm

I'm new to Pact and new to groovy too.

I want to write a Pact to hand it to a provider.

The provider should answer on a given request with an array of strings **like** `["foo", "bar", "foobar"]`.

Here is my working state, which is stripped to the neccessary parts but still is executable:

```
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.groovy.PactBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import spock.lang.Specification

class MyPact extends Specification {
    def "some test"() {
        given:
        when:

        def pactBuilder = new PactBuilder()
        pactBuilder {
            serviceConsumer "consumer"
            hasPactWith "provider"
            port 1234
            given('some provider state')
            uponReceiving('a request')
            withAttributes(method: 'get', path: '/my/endpoint')
            willRespondWith(status: 200)
            withBody(["foo", "bar", "foobar"])
        }

        pactBuilder.run() { mockServer ->
            RESTClient('http://localhost:1234/').get(path: '/my/endpoint')
        }

        then: 1 == 1

    }
}
```

This test generates the following pact file:

```
{
  "provider": {
    "name": "provider"
  },
  "consumer": {
    "name": "consumer"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
      "description": "a request",
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/my/endpoint"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": [
          "foo",
          "bar",
          "foobar"
        ]
      },
      "providerStates": [
        {
          "name": "some provider state"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pact-specification": {
      "version": "3.0.0"
    },
    "pact-jvm": {
      "version": "3.5.6"
    }
  }
}
```

The Pact file expects the provider to always answer with `["foo", "bar", "foobar"]`

What I want is a generic array of Strings.

When I try the following:

```
withBody {
    key eachLike (3, "foo")
}
```

the generated Pact file looks like:

```
{
  "provider": {
    "name": "provider"
  },
  "consumer": {
    "name": "consumer"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
      "description": "a request",
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/my/endpoint"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": {
          "key": [
            "foo",
            "foo",
            "foo"
          ]
        },
        "matchingRules": {
          "body": {
            "$.key": {
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ],
              "combine": "AND"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "providerStates": [
        {
          "name": "some provider state"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pact-specification": {
      "version": "3.0.0"
    },
    "pact-jvm": {
      "version": "3.5.6"
    }
  }
}
```

There are matchingRules and this looks good.
But there is an object on the root level and I need the array to be the root.

Is there a way to get the array as root element and the strings matched by type not by value?

Comment: This is a duplicate of another question asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523414/pact-groovy-mock-with-array-in-body
I believe that this may be a bug.  There's already an issue posted on github: https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues/555
If you could please tack onto that conversation with your example, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I think it is another issue. In the linked question the problem is, that only 1 entry is created in the body.

My Issue is to create a body like:

       ` "body": [
          "foo",
          "bar",
          "foobar"
        ]`

and a matcher like:

        `"matchingRules": {
          "body": {
            "$.key": {
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ],
              "combine": "AND"
            }
          }
        }`

but without the `.key`

Comment: okay, the issue doesn't cover your matcher, but does cover the body array problem.  Maybe create a different issue for the key matcher problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created an issue at github: https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues/557